# cannot generate report in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Elasticsearch 8.7.1 my cluster consists of 2 nodes
and Kibana version is 8.7.1,
I am facing a problem with generating CSV it was working normally, but two weeks from now it's stopped
with the error "reporting task runner has not been initialized!"
the full error is below
`Error: Internal Server Error at fetch_Fetch.fetchResponse (http://x.x.x.x:5601/61224/bundles/core/core.entry.js:1:275461) at async http://x.x.x.x:5601/61224/bundles/core/core.entry.js:1:273517 at async http://x.x.x.x:5601/61224/bundles/core/core.entry.js:1:273474`
when I open the reporting page in Kibana i find the report status pending
below a part from logging in kibana.log
can anyone help

```
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.6.0"},"@timestamp":"2023-11-10T16:18:47.172+02:00","message":"Setting up [132] plugins: [translations,monitoringCollection,licensing,globalSearch,globalSearchProviders,features,mapsEms,licenseApiGuard,customBranding,usageCollection,taskManager,cloud,guidedOnboarding,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetryCollectionXpack,kibanaUsageCollection,share,screenshotMode,banners,newsfeed,ftrApis,fieldFormats,expressions,screenshotting,dataViews,charts,esUiShared,customIntegrations,home,searchprofiler,painlessLab,grokdebugger,management,cloudDataMigration,advancedSettings,spaces,security,snapshotRestore,lists,encryptedSavedObjects,telemetry,licenseManagement,files,eventLog,actions,notifications,console,contentManagement,bfetch,data,watcher,fileUpload,ingestPipelines,ecsDataQualityDashboard,alerting,unifiedSearch,unifiedFieldList,savedSearch,savedObjects,graph,savedObjectsTagging,savedObjectsManagement,eventAnnotation,embeddable,reporting,uiActionsEnhanced,presentationUtil,expressionShape,expressionRevealImage,expressionRepeatImage,expressionMetric,expressionImage,controls,dataViewFieldEditor,triggersActionsUi,transform,stackConnectors,stackAlerts,ruleRegistry,visualizations,canvas,visTypeXy,visTypeVislib,visTypeVega,visTypeTimeseries,visTypeTimelion,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeTable,visTypeMetric,visTypeHeatmap,visTypeMarkdown,dashboard,dashboardEnhanced,expressionXY,expressionTagcloud,expressionPartitionVis,visTypePie,expressionMetricVis,expressionLegacyMetricVis,expressionHeatmap,expressionGauge,lens,maps,cases,timelines,sessionView,kubernetesSecurity,threatIntelligence,aiops,discover,observability,fleet,osquery,indexManagement,rollup,remoteClusters,crossClusterReplication,indexLifecycleManagement,cloudSecurityPosture,discoverEnhanced,dataVisualizer,ml,synthetics,securitySolution,infra,upgradeAssistant,monitoring,logstash,enterpriseSearch,apm,visTypeGauge,dataViewManagement]","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"plugins-system.standard"},"process":{"pid":1248286},"trace":{"id":"93651a49c2a822f96592f8d01f6540df"},"transaction":{"id":"7513aef5dc31ba56"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.6.0"},"@timestamp":"2023-11-10T16:18:48.755+02:00","message":"Starting [132] plugins: [translations,monitoringCollection,licensing,globalSearch,globalSearchProviders,features,mapsEms,licenseApiGuard,customBranding,usageCollection,taskManager,cloud,guidedOnboarding,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetryCollectionXpack,kibanaUsageCollection,share,screenshotMode,banners,newsfeed,ftrApis,fieldFormats,expressions,screenshotting,dataViews,charts,esUiShared,customIntegrations,home,searchprofiler,painlessLab,grokdebugger,management,cloudDataMigration,advancedSettings,spaces,security,snapshotRestore,lists,encryptedSavedObjects,telemetry,licenseManagement,files,eventLog,actions,notifications,console,contentManagement,bfetch,data,watcher,fileUpload,ingestPipelines,ecsDataQualityDashboard,alerting,unifiedSearch,unifiedFieldList,savedSearch,savedObjects,graph,savedObjectsTagging,savedObjectsManagement,eventAnnotation,embeddable,reporting,uiActionsEnhanced,presentationUtil,expressionShape,expressionRevealImage,expressionRepeatImage,expressionMetric,expressionImage,controls,dataViewFieldEditor,triggersActionsUi,transform,stackConnectors,stackAlerts,ruleRegistry,visualizations,canvas,visTypeXy,visTypeVislib,visTypeVega,visTypeTimeseries,visTypeTimelion,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeTable,visTypeMetric,visTypeHeatmap,visTypeMarkdown,dashboard,dashboardEnhanced,expressionXY,expressionTagcloud,expressionPartitionVis,visTypePie,expressionMetricVis,expressionLegacyMetricVis,expressionHeatmap,expressionGauge,lens,maps,cases,timelines,sessionView,kubernetesSecurity,threatIntelligence,aiops,discover,observability,fleet,osquery,indexManagement,rollup,remoteClusters,crossClusterReplication,indexLifecycleManagement,cloudSecurityPosture,discoverEnhanced,dataVisualizer,ml,synthetics,securitySolution,infra,upgradeAssistant,monitoring,logstash,enterpriseSearch,apm,visTypeGauge,dataViewManagement]","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"plugins-system.standard"},"process":{"pid":1248286},"trace":{"id":"80c1f60306ba40d95b4f5784a98fc653"},"transaction":{"id":"06deb06b50d6cdd2"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.6.0"},"@timestamp":"2023-11-10T16:19:04.129+02:00","message":"Reporting task runner has not been initialized!","error":{"message":"Reporting task runner has not been initialized!","type":"Error","stack_trace":"Error: Reporting task runner has not been initialized!\n    at ExecuteReportTask.getTaskManagerStart (/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins/reporting/server/lib/tasks/execute_report.js:113:13)\n    at ExecuteReportTask.scheduleTask (/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins/reporting/server/lib/tasks/execute_report.js:405:23)\n    at ReportingCore.scheduleTask (/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins/reporting/server/core.js:221:35)\n    at RequestHandler.enqueueJob (/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins/reporting/server/routes/lib/request_handler.js:98:34)\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n    at RequestHandler.handleGenerateRequest (/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins/reporting/server/routes/lib/request_handler.js:130:16)\n    at /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins/reporting/server/routes/generate/generate_from_jobparams.js:95:14\n    at Router.handle (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@kbn/core-http-router-server-internal/src/router.js:141:30)\n    at handler (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@kbn/core-http-router-server-internal/src/router.js:107:50)\n    at exports.Manager.execute (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/toolkit.js:60:28)\n    at Object.internals.handler (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/handler.js:46:20)\n    at exports.execute (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/handler.js:31:20)\n    at Request._lifecycle (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/request.js:371:32)\n    at Request._execute (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/request.js:281:9)"},"log":{"level":"ERROR","logger":"plugins.reporting"},"process":{"pid":1248286},"trace":{"id":"d4d193d1bcfea2639c8ab9182672cf39"},"transaction":{"id":"ff84bdf6896b47fc"}}
```

i had checked the logs and found nothing
restart kibana, install another kibana instence didnt help

Comment: How big is your Kibana node ? In term of RAM.

Comment: 8 gb RAM 
16 Core
150 GB Hdd

Comment: Can you kill that pending reporting task and restart Kibana? What happens?

Comment: nothing i deleted the pending and tried again with no success the order is stuck as pending